# Send filepath to textbox on other form

Tags: vb.net, filepath

In my class i want to return the filepath into a tectbox on an other form, but it won't return the filepath after saving. Probally because it is a sub an't won't return a value am i correct? But what is the right way to fix this?

```
Friend Sub GetFilepath(ByVal hide As Boolean)
    Dim GeluidS As New GeluidSchermForm
    Call ExcelKoppelen("Z:\location\Geluidscherm_template.xls")
    Filepath = Xl.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Excel document (*.xls), *.xls", , , )
    Workbook.SaveAs(Filepath)
    GeluidS.Excelfilenaam.Text = Filepath
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Friend Function GetFilepath(ByVal hide As Boolean) as String
    Dim GeluidS As New GeluidSchermForm
    Call ExcelKoppelen("Z:\location\Geluidscherm_template.xls")
    Filepath = Xl.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Excel document (*.xls), *.xls", , , )
    Workbook.SaveAs(Filepath)
    GeluidS.Excelfilenaam.Text = Filepath
    return Filepath
End Sub
```

Like that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it still won't return the filepath.

Comment: Guess I need more context. You are trying to return Filepath? What is the type of Filepath?

Comment: My vb project is at the office, so will try to explain what i have.

Comment: My vb project is at the office, so will try to explain what i have. I have a form called GeluidSchermForm, on that form i have a button which calls for GetFilepath on class1. Getfilepath will then call Excelkoppelen, Excelkoppelen will open excel with the right file etc and will then return to GetFilepath. GetFilepath saves the template file somewhere and it should pass the file path back to the text box called Excelfilenaam.text on the GeluidSchermForm form.

Comment: Filepath is just a Dim Filepath as string located on the top of class1. I hope you understand how i wanted to work. You probably ask why don't you just use it on GeluidSchermForm itself, but the problem is that this method is called many times from different forms.

Answer (score 0):

If your provided method is within the form you want to grab the filename FROM...

You can create a ReadOoly property that returns a global variable and access it before the form is disposed.

```
textbox1.Text = frm.filePath
```

Also, you can write a function to just return the global variable and call it before you dispose the form.

```
textbox1.Text = frm.getPath()
```

Depending on how `GetFilePath()` is used it may not work. You'd have to call it from outside the form, where the instance of the form was created. It's hard to tell how it's being used with just the method.